# firefox do not set iframe designMode to on with Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, firefox, iframe, angularjs-directive, rich-text-editor

I want to create a rich text editor with angular directive.
The designMode Attr work well in Chrome, Opera and other chrome base browser but did not work in FireFox, Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ow6BxOAneLsNjkyZmGiy) to see in action :

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/Ow6BxOAneLsNjkyZmGiy
```

But when the browser loading we can set designMode to on in firefox console :

```
document.getElementById('richtextfield').contentDocument.designMode = 'on';
```

We can easily logged iframe on angular directive to firefox console :

```
console.log( element.find( 'iframe' )[0] );
```

Why this happening ??

Answer (score 0):

> If you are trying to add this Iframe on a SSL-encrypted website (https://), **it won't work any more since Firefox 23 because Mozilla has decided to blocked all unencrypted content on encrypted websites** (for example http-iframes on https-websites). You can change this behaviour in your own Firefox installation by typing about:config in the address bar and setting security.mixed_content.block_active_content to false. But that won't help you for all other FF23-visitors on your website.

Comment: I'm set `security.mixed_content.block_active_content to false` but did not solve the problem. Although I running the project in localhost without any SSL-encrypted

Comment: you can check ff forum https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/737230 , my suggestion is to avoid iframe and use angular templates..

Comment: Please try open [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ow6BxOAneLsNjkyZmGiy) in your firefox and see you have the this problem also ?